# Knockout Observable Array becomes exponentially slower

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, bigdata

I would like a good answer here, not looking for any answers that are 'Have you tried X?', would rather have a knowledgeable source with a firm answer.

I have an observable array that I am using to fill in a chart.  The observable array could contain up to 10k POJO's that are retrieved from Breeze.js in the local cache.  When I first go out and get the data from the server, and then make a call against the local cache it is returned almost instantaneously.

On the next call, it gets exponentially slower.  The objects being returned are not each observables nor do they contain observables, since I am performing a Breeze query with select they are POJO's.  The problem  is they continue to get slower and slower as I go back and continue to get the same data set.  It is almost leading me to think somehow I am creating a memory leak in the observable array somehow.

#### In my view -

```
<h1>There are <span data-bind="text: chartData().length"></span> chart items</h1>
```

#### In my view model -

```
var chartData = ko.computed(function () {
    var myArray = ko.observableArray();
    var params = { xmin: xMin(), xmax: xMax() };
    if (!initialized) { return myArray(); }
    datacontext.getData(myArray, params.xmin, params.xmax false);
    return myArray();
}).extend({ throttle: 2000 });
```

#### In a datacontext.js file where the query is executing -

```
if (!forceRemote) {
    var thisData = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
    myObservable([]);
    var myArray = myObservable();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(myArray, thisData);
    return myObservable.valueHasMutated();
}
```

I tried the arrayPushAll and value mutation based on a recommendation from another SO.com question but it doesn't appear to be any faster than setting myObservable([]) and then setting it equal to thisData.

Because of the large data set I would like to reduce this to as short of a recalculation as possible.

The reason I am  setting the xmin and xmax as params is to make the computed dependent on the two observables...

Comment: Is it still slow if you remove the arrayPushAll and myObservable.valueHasMutated? i.e. just time the query. If so, it may be a Breeze bug and I will run some tests. If not, then its a pure knockout issue and maybe you can recreate it with a much simpler example.

Comment: Could you provide more information on where else `xMin` and `xMax` are getting used?  If they're values are getting updated as a result of the datacontext.getData function executing, chartData's dependency on them will cause chartData to re-evaluate itself and call datacontext.getData again.  Could this be what's causing your infinite loop?

Comment: Nope they are not.  They are chart data.  I am not worried about the loop issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify your computed observable. There is rarely ever a reason to create an observable within a computed observable.

```
var chartData = ko.computed(function () {
    var min = xMin(), max = xMax(); // ensure we have a dependency
    return !initialized ? [] : datacontext.getData(min, max, false);
}).extend({ throttle: 2000 });
```

The query just needs to return the data:

```
if (!forceRemote) {
    var thisData = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
    return thisData;
}
```

EDIT:

Assuming that you've already loaded all the data and stored it in an array, your computed observable can use `ko.utils.arrayFilter` to calculate filtered results:

```
var chartData = ko.computed(function () {
    var min = xMin(), max = xMax(); // ensure we have a dependency
    return !initialized ? [] : ko.utils.arrayFilter(dataArray, function(item) {
        return item.x >= min && item.x <= max;
    });
});
```

Comment: What would decrease the amount of processing time with this solution?  Or why at least

Comment: Your code has an observable with absolutely no purpose, which only makes the code more confusing. Each time your computed observable updates, it has to dispose the subscription to the previous useless observable and create a new subscription to a new useless observable. It can only get faster by taking that observable out.

Comment: So the processing time doesn't seem to have any noticeable changes, if anything it is milliseconds from a 5 second operation.  The bulk of the time may just be Breeze executing the query locally, do you think using any of the Knockout utils would be more useful for filtering?  I haven't tried using ko.utils.arrayFilter() with more than one property to filter on, any thoughts there?

Comment: I've added an example of using ko.utils.arrayFilter

Comment: Accepted the answer, not really seeing a huge performance increase but I think it is just due to the size of the data, both of your answers are valid answers so thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I myself found Knockout to be slow when filtering, notably on IE8. Unfortunately this is still a supported browser for me :-( The problem was that I was filtering a large collection with complex html templates. The IE8 rendering engine was having a fit and kept throwing "slow running script" alerts.

I resolved this by using the CSS 'display' property. I added a visible Observable for each of the elements in the collection, and the following data-bind. ( where hidden is a css class with display:none; )

```
data-bind="css:{'hidden':visible()===false}"
```

Then all you have to do is loop through the collection and set the property as desired. This made a massive difference in my case.